# How can I pass my parameter query dates to the report header

Tags: ms-access, report

How can I get the two date values from my MS Access parameter query and put them in my MS Access report header? I have used very little VBA so was wondering if there was a way to do it without too much code or even a simple trick if I am lucky.
The fields are ContactSource (this is where the contact came from. FaceBook/Ebay/Friend etc) Sale date is the date the sale was made which is entered in a form for the contacts details.
Attached the is query view[image: Query View]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve the problem was to add in two fields as expressions which looked like this.

```
SELECT Count(Contact.ContactSource) AS [Number of Sales], Contact.ContactSource, 
[Start Date] AS StartDate, [End Date] AS EndDate
FROM Contact
WHERE (((Contact.SaleDate)>=[Start Date] And (Contact.SaleDate)<=[End Date]))
GROUP BY Contact.ContactSource
ORDER BY Count(Contact.ContactSource) DESC;
```

This meant that I could then select the fields in the report like you would any other field in the table/query.
I hope this helps someone else as it took me awhile to figure out.